# Views positioned incorrectly on Secondary Monitor, MainWindow on Primary Monitor

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Using the MFC, VS2017

I have an MFC application, and the main form is derived from

```
CMDIFrameWndEx
```

Then there are 5 Child Windows (and I have verified that WS_CHILD attribute is set) of type

```
CMiniFrameWnd
```

each containing either CFormView or CListView embedded within. All of these embedded windows are created via CreateView(). Now the odd thing is all of the 5 CMiniFrameWnd's all are positioned on the secondary monitor and I don't know why. I have examined the ClientRect coordinates via GetClientRect() for the 5 CMiniFrameWnd's and they look normal with respect to CMDIFrameWndEx.
I am using SetWindowPos() to position all 5.

I don't understand why Child Windows appear on the Secondary Monitor as the main Window is on the Primary  Monitor. I am not using MonitorFromWindow() but I should not need to as it is on the Primary.

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Child Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#child-windows): *"A child window has the `WS_CHILD` style and is **confined to the client area of its parent window**."* If your 'child' windows are positioned outside the 'parent', then those aren't actually child windows. There's something wrong in the code we cannot see.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It is GrandParent-Parent-Child relationship. The CFormView, CListView is a WS_CHILD of CMiniFrameWnd, but CMiniFrameWnd is not a child of CMDIFrameWndEx, it is a top-level window. I tried making it so and CWnd::CreateEx() failed.But I should be able to crack this. I think it is the coordinate system. I have the MFC source code and I noticed CWnd::CenterWindow is capable of centering top-level windows, therefore I should examine that.

Comment: The important point was, that you are asking about an issue with your code, but haven't published that code in the question. A [mcve] is generally required. That said, I believe MFC automatically stores its UI layout into the registry (at least it did that at one time), and tries to restore it on application startup. Given that it's near impossible to reliably map window coordinates to display devices in a way that accommodates serialization, it may well be that something is going wrong there.

Comment: @IInspectable I see you quoted MS documentation, but a child window with additional WS_POPUP style can be located outside the parent's window area. Is this wrong?

Comment: Nick, MS documentation is wrong.The basic thing is if the Window has the WS_CHILD attribute, coordinates are Client coordinates but if not, coordinates are Screen coordinates. WS_POPUP is mutually exclusive with WS_CHILD, therefore WS_POPUP windows are top-level windows, therefore coordinates are  Screen coordinates.

Comment: @nic: [Windows Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles): *"`WS_CHILD`: The window is a child window. A window with this style cannot have a menu bar. **This style cannot be used with the `WS_POPUP` style.**"* In short, the documentation is accurate. A child window is confined to the client area of its parent window. Always.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the last thing, yes I am doing something fundamentally wrong. The problem is now solved.

If SetWindowPos() or MoveWindow() is used, the coordinates supplied **must be** Screen coordinates. That was my error. I had supplied Client coordinates got from GetClientRect(). Using GetWindowRect() gives Screen coordinates. This was for saving/restoring Windows positions to/from the registry. But the correct functions to use to save/restore Window positions are GetWindowPlacement()/SetWindowPlacement().